# Orientación para vídeos

Tags: javascript, video, windows-mobile

Necesito un poco de ayuda. No me funciona del todo este código de orientationchange para vídeo. Solo usando doy Play al vídeo y volteo el móvil muestra pantalla completa. Luego no puede salir de allí.

```
var vid =  document.querySelector("video");

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

//(if) Para todos los 
navegadores
if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
vid.requestFullscreen();

} else {
//Solo para Chrome

 vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta analizar la orientación del dispositivo para analizar si entras en pantalla completa o no. `window.orientation` tiene 4 valores posibles: 0, 180 para horizontal y 90, -90 para vertical.

```
var vid =  document.querySelector("video");

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    let angle = window.orientation;
    if(angle == 0 || angle == 180) {
        // Salir de pantalla completa
    if(document.fullScreenElement) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
    }
    } else {
        //(if) Para todos los  navegadores
        if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
            vid.requestFullscreen();
        } else {
            //Solo para Chrome
            vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation